# An inequality using column sums of inverse matrices

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I want to prove a matrix analogue to inequality $\left(\frac{1-x(1-\alpha)}{\alpha}\right)^{\alpha} x^{1-\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in [0,1)$ and $x \in [0,1]$, which has a nice proof using GM-AM, as shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4176762/165163.

Let $A=\{a_{ij}\}$ be an $N \times N$ strictly substochastic matrix, $\alpha_i \equiv 1 - \sum_j a_{ij} $, $x$ be a scalar, and $f(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $$f(x) = \prod_{i}\left(\frac{\sum_{l}w_{li}(1)}{\sum_{l}w_{li}(x)}\right)^{\frac{\sum_{j}w_{ji}\left(1\right)\alpha_{i}}{\bar{w}}}x^{\frac{\bar{w}-N}{\bar{w}}},$$
where $w_{ij}(x)$ are the elements of matrix $W(x) \equiv \left(I-xA\right)^{-1}$ and
$\bar{w}\equiv\sum_{i,j}w_{ij}$.

I want to show that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

It is clear that $f(1) = 1$ and that $f(0) = 0.$ Also, note that $\sum_i w_{ji}(1) \alpha_i = 1$ for all $j$, which follows from
$$ \{ \sum_i w_{ji}(1) \alpha_i \} = W(1)\left(I-\mathcal{D}\left\{ A\iota\right\} \right)\iota=W(1)\left(I-A\right)\iota=\left(I-A\right)^{-1}\left(I-A\right)\iota=\iota.$$
This implies that the sum of the powers in the terms above is 1, $$\sum_i \frac{\sum_j w_{ji}(1)\alpha_i}{\bar{w}} + \frac{\bar{w}-N}{\bar{w}} = 1.$$ Thus, we can think of $f(x)$ as a geometric mean. But the arithmetic mean corresponding to this geometric mean, namely
$$ \sum_{i} \left(\frac{\sum_{j}w_{ji}\left(1\right)\alpha_{i}}{\bar{w}}\right) \left(\frac{\sum_{l}w_{li}(1)}{\sum_{l}w_{li}(x)}\right) + \left(\frac{\bar{w}-N}{\bar{w}} \right) x $$
does not equal one, so the GM-AM approach didn't work immediately in this case, except in the case in which $A$ is diagonal, where the expression just below collapses to
$$ \sum_{i} \left(\frac{1}{\bar{w}}\right) \left(\frac{1-x (1-\alpha_i)}{\alpha_i}\right) + \left(\frac{\bar{w}-N}{\bar{w}} \right) x =1, $$ and so the desired inequality follows from the GM-AM.

Simulations suggest that the inequality holds -- in fact, they suggest that $f(x)$ is always increasing. I could try to show $f'(x) \geq 0$ but this would limit how much I can then generalize, for example to having $x$ be a vector, in which case $f(x):\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $$f(x)= \prod_{i}\left(\frac{\sum_{l}w_{li}(1)}{\sum_{l}w_{li}(x)}\right)^{\frac{\sum_{j}w_{ji}\left(1\right)\alpha_{i}}{\bar{w}}} \prod_i x_i^{\frac{\sum_j w_{ij}-N}{\bar{w}}},$$
where $w_{ij}(x)$ are now the elements of matrix $\left(I-A \mathrm{diag}(x)\right)^{-1}$

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Differentiation shows that $d\ln f(x) / d\ln x$ is nonnegative iff $$\sum_{i}\left(\sum_{k}\sum_{h}v_{kh}v_{hi}\alpha_{i}\right)\left(\frac{\sum_{j}w_{ji}}{\sum_{l}v_{li}}\right)<\bar{w}.$$ In matrix notation, this is equivalent to $$\iota^{T}\left(I-diag\left(A\iota\right)\right)diag\left(W^{T}\iota\right)diag\left(V^{T}\iota\right)^{-1}V^{T}V^{T}\iota\leq\iota^{T}W\iota.$$ Letting $S\left(A\right)=\left(\mathcal{D}\left(A\iota\right)\right)^{-1}A,$ this can be shown to be equivalent to $$\iota^{T}\left(S(W^{T})\right)^{-1}S(V^{T})V^{T}\iota\leq\iota^{T}W\iota.$$ How to proceed?

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment, the fifth line uses $\mathcal{D}(A)$ instead of the more standard $diag{A}$, which I used in the fourth line.

Comment: Note that if $x=1$ then $$\iota^{T}\left(S(W^{T})\right)^{-1}S(V^{T})V^{T}\iota=\iota^{T}\left(S(W^{T})\right)^{-1}S(W^{T})W^{T}\iota=\iota^{T}W^{T}\iota=\iota^{T}W\iota,$$ while if $x=0$ then $$\iota^{T}\left(S(W^{T})\right)^{-1}\iota=\iota^{T}W^{-T}\mathrm{diag}\left(W^{T}\iota\right)\iota=\iota^{T}W^{-T}W^{T}\iota=\iota^{T}I\iota.$$

Comment: @Saad: extensive simulations suggest it is true. The background is in economics.

Comment: @Andres have you proven the result for diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: @mathworker21 no. Do you think this is a good thing to try?

Comment: @Andres i think it would imply the result, since diagonalizable matrices are dense (and your function, as a function of $x$ and the matrix, is continuous when restricted to matrices with non-negative entries and row-sum at most $1-\epsilon$ for some fixed $\epsilon > 0$).

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks, this could be very useful, but just to be sure: which is the matrix that we would assume is diagonalizable? I imagine it is $A$, right?

Comment: @Andres yes ${}{}$

Comment: Since you mentioned possible generalization to the cases where $x$ is a vector, could you elaborate in what form will such a generalization be? This would more clearly deprecate certain methods.

Comment: @Saad I edited the question so that at the end it describes the vector case. Thanks.

Comment: @Andres It is what you want ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_inequality

Comment: @ErikSatie Maybe, and would be great to have something well established linked to my inequality, but I don't see the connection with the Grothendieck inequality. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @mathworker21 If $A$ is diagonizable then $A=P^{-1} D P$, and hence $$\sum_l w_{li}(x) =\sum_{l,k} \frac{P^{-1}_{lk} P_{ki}}{1-xd_{kk}}.$$ How do I proceed from here?